# Simplified matrix notation

Tags: matrices, notation

There is a mathematical notation to define an array that you can write using standard keyboard characters on one line? for example:

```
  1  3  8  7
 10 17 22  6
  5 10 23  8
 11 98  7 12
```

Comment: When entering matrices into MATLAB, entries are listed in row order seperated by semicolons. Your matrix would be written as: `[1 3 8 7; 10 17 22 6; 5 10 23 8; 11 98 7 12]`

Comment: Was very helpful, but this is just an example of notation used in MATLAB or is a mathematical model? It is something already known and accepted if I submit this notation?

Comment: I would say that MATLAB notation is widely recognized. As long as you're clear about the notation that you're using you should be fine. If you'd like to learn about typesetting math on this website (and to some extent elsewhere) have a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: I read this tutorial to get into the topic I found quite interesting, but as soon as the MATLAB MathJax is a specifc program, I am not challenging the validity of the model MATLAB, I have very limited knowledge of it. And despite searching I could not find the answer. What I was wondering is if for example, a scientific calculator would be acceptable this kind of notation.

Comment: If you're trying to enter a matrix into a specific calculator, the notation is going to depend on that calculator. From your other question it sounds like you're trying to develop a calculator. In that case the notation is entirely up to you, but MATLAB's notation wouldn't be a bad place to start. As far as I am aware, there is no standard one-line matrix notation.

Comment: Thank you, I have no more doubts!

Comment: Why would a mathematician, as opposed to a programmer, ever need to use such notation? Putting things on one line makes them easier for computers to read but makes them harder for *people* to read, and mathematicians still (mostly) write for people.

Comment: In my example, i am not concerned with how a person is going to read, but I'll pass on the way to the program, I'll have to write a lexical analyzer to interpret it, so insert two issues here. The way the user will interact not necessarily need to be this, but do not want to reinvent the wheel. If there is a notation my preference is to use. It is important for me to analyze the fewest entries from more standardized as possible.